# How to start a nodejs project with only index.js and package.json and node modules files

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, node-modules

I have three files 
-- Index.js
-- Node Modules
-- Package.json

I need to run this project I am using

```
 npm start
```

But getting the below error

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

Then i have used the below command in package.json

```
start:"node index.js"
```

Then the project is running but coming out of loop like the below

```
admin@DESKTOP-ASA7V3C MINGW64 /e/Trigger Email Fucntion
$ npm start

> skill-sample-nodejs-fact-i18n@2.0.0 start E:\Trigger Email Fucntion
> node index.js

Loading function

admin@DESKTOP-ASA7V3C MINGW64 /e/Trigger Email Fucntion
$
```

So please help me how to start the node js project and not to stop unless we stop it

Expected Result :

The project needs to run by using npm start

Comment: So the core problem here is that you have not actually included the content of `index.js` that you are attempting to "run" in your question. Without that, it is basically impossible for anyone to make an informed and accurate response that can actually solve your issue, or otherwise point you to the correct things you nee to be learning. I suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center here, as there are usefuly guidelines in to what is generally expected of a "question" and how to get a meaningful response.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is the expected behaviour, code exits once it's execution is complete. You can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), it will detect the changes and automatically start the node application. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Anand ,
Thanks for the quick response
But one doubt regarding node mon

if we are using node mon it is showing 
```[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```
is the project is running eventhough it throws like this??

Comment: @Sudhin It's a firm doubt. The problem with the "answer" and indeed the question is that you don't actually show any code content of `index.js` in order for anyone to make an informed judgement about what exactly went wrong here. When you don't do that, then what you get in response is a "guess" rather than an **answer**. I hope I have made my point clear. My advice is to edit your question with detail about what the content of `index.js` is, and let someone make an informed response, rather than a guess.